# Run-time error '438' - Option Button Visibility \\ VBA

Tags: vba, visibility, radio-button

Form Controls In Use. Error:

[image: Error Code Pop Up]

Not proficient in coding but I am attempting to produce a simple Hide/Show macro for use on an option button on a sheet. I am receiving an error code when on the...

```
 Worksheets("Door and Frame Options").OptionButton("Option Button 5").Visible = False
```

part of the code, has anyone ever come across this before?

```
Sub Btn_BespokePaint()

If Worksheets("Template Information").Range("P15").Value = 1 Then

    Worksheets("Door and Frame Options").OptionButton("Option Button 5").Visible = False

End If

If Worksheets("Template Information").Range("P15").Value = 2 Then

    Worksheets("Door and Frame Options").OptionButton("Option Button 5").Visible = True

End If

'Help

End Sub
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: `Worksheets("Door and Frame Options").OptionButtons("Option Button 5").Visible = False` With an S to `OptionButtons` since you want the collection.

Comment: @VincentG You should post that as an answer. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Well, it is not documented, and doesn't shows up in Intellisense. Juste a lucky try and guess on my side.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the collection of Option Buttons, you can use the OptionButton**s** Collection, with an S:

```
Worksheets("Door and Frame Options").OptionButtons("Option Button 5").Visible = False
```

You can also use the Shapes Collection, but you will have other type of shapes mixed in.

Comment: The shapes bit won't matter if referring directly by name and not iterating over the entire collection. + 1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Select Case Worksheets("Template Information").Range("P15").Value

    Case 1
        Worksheets("Door and Frame Options").Shapes("Option Button 5").Visible = False
    Case 2
        Worksheets("Door and Frame Options").Shapes("Option Button 5").Visible = True

    End Select

End Sub
```